# why this method cannot be annotated as @tailrec?

Tags: scala

caculate sum of list: but this method cannot be annotated as @tailrec?

```
 def rec(a:List[Int]): Int ={

  def rechelper(a:List[Int],n:Int,res:Int) :Int={
    if (n==a.length) res 
    else  rechelper(a,n+1,res+a(n))  
  }
  rechelper(a,0,0)
}
```

Comment: `rechelper` _can_ be annotated with `@tailrec`...

Comment: It isn't recursive *at all*, how could it possibly be *tail-recursive* if it isn't even recursive?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do so because rec method is not tail recursive. rechelper is tail recursive method so you can do that.

```
scala>  def rec(a:List[Int]): Int ={
     |    @tailrec
     |   def rechelper(a:List[Int],n:Int,res:Int) :Int={
     |     if (n==a.length) res 
     |     else  rechelper(a,n+1,res+a(n))  
     |   }
     |   rechelper(a,0,0)
     | }
rec: (a: List[Int])Int

scala>
```